# Logstash/Grok: Read substring from field using regex

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I'm trying to extract a substring from my request_uri field in logstash. Grok splits my apace access-log line into several field (is already working) so I get the request_uri in its own field. Now I want to get the root context of the uri.

```
/en/some/stuff
/ApplicationName/some/path
/fr/some/french/stuff
```

But I don#t know how to store en, ApplicationName, fr in its own field (additional to the others). I'm thinking something like this might work.

```
grok {
            pattern => "\"%{GREEDYDATA:domain}\" - %{IP:client_ip} \[%{GREEDYDATA:log_timestamp}\] \"%{WORD:method}\" \"%{GREEDYDATA:request_uri}\" - \"%{GREEDYDATA:query_string}\" - \"%{GREEDYDATA:protocol}\" - %{NUMBER:http_statuscode} %{NUMBER:bytes} \"%{GREEDYDATA:user_agent}\" %{NUMBER:seconds} %{NUMBER:milliseconds} \"%{GREEDYDATA:server_node}\""
            match => [ "new_context_field", "SOME-REGEX fo parse request_uri" ]
        }
```

Can you give me a hint?

Comment: Which Logstash version is this? I've never heard of a `pattern` option to the grok filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for your help. Solved it with this grok config which is pretty similar to your suggestion.

```
grok {
    patterns_dir => "/path/to/elk-stack/logstash-1.4.2/bin/custom_patterns"

    match => [ "message", "\"%{GREEDYDATA:domain}\" - %{IP:client_ip} \[%{GREEDYDATA:log_timestamp}\] \"%{WORD:method}\" \"%{GREEDYDATA:request_uri}\" - \"%{GREEDYDATA:query_string}\" - \"%{GREEDYDATA:protocol}\" - %{NUMBER:http_statuscode} %{NUMBER:bytes} \"%{GREEDYDATA:user_agent}\" %{NUMBER:seconds} %{NUMBER:milliseconds} \"%{GREEDYDATA:server_node}\""]
    match => [ "request_uri", "%{CONTEXTFROMURI:context}" ]

    break_on_match => false
}
```

To use multiple matches in a single grok block make sure to include `break_on_match => false`. Otherwise the second match is skipped if first one is successful.

Answer (score 2):

Your [grok filter](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/grok) should actually look like this:

```
grok {
  match => [
    "message",
    "\"%{GREEDYDATA:domain}\" - %{IP:client_ip} \[%{GREEDYDATA:log_timestamp}\] \"%{WORD:method}\" \"%{GREEDYDATA:request_uri}\" - \"%{GREEDYDATA:query_string}\" - \"%{GREEDYDATA:protocol}\" - %{NUMBER:http_statuscode} %{NUMBER:bytes} \"%{GREEDYDATA:user_agent}\" %{NUMBER:seconds} %{NUMBER:milliseconds} \"%{GREEDYDATA:server_node}\""
  ]
}
```

Then, use a second grok filter after the one that matches against the whole log message in the 'message' field:

```
grok {
  match => ["request_uri", "/(?<context>[^/]+)"]
}
```